# Как получить данные пользователя при использовании Azure Active Directory для аутентификации?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure, asp.net-core-webapi

Я разрабатываю приложение на ASP.NET Core Web API. Для аутентификации использою Azure Active Directory. Пользователь может войти в свою учётную запись Azure и получить токен. С помощью этого токена он получает доступ к методам контроллеров, на которых стоит атрибут Authorize.
Но как можно получить данные этого пользователя, чтобы сохранить их в мою базу данных?

Comment: можно достать текущего пользователя из IHttpContextAccessor, там будут все claims, которые содержатся в токене

Comment: примерно так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36641907/1988244

Comment: Зависит от места где вы получаете. Прямо в контроллере можно получить через HttpContext.User.Identity.UserId или выше Indentity просмотреть Claims, либо использовать ContextAccessor который предварительно зарегистрировать в Startup.cs